# Switch logo on scroll down

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a relatively tall logo on a WordPress based website.

When the user scrolls down, the header section becomes a sticky, fixed area and is always displayed at the top.

Is there a way that I can replace the logo with another one (which is a horizontal, smaller version) when the user has scrolled down passed a certain position?

I've done a quick search and can't seem to find any similar problems in the forum.

This is the current code in the header.php file displaying the logo:

```
<div class="logo-container">
  <a <?php echo $img_logo? '' : 'class="text-logo" '; ?>id="logo" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
    <?php
    if($img_logo)
        a13_header_logo_image();

    else
        echo $apollo13->get_option( 'appearance', 'logo_text' );
    ?>
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm not too sure how to implement this but any help would be greatly appreciated, 
 Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you have so far. *Note: The [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article states that you should "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap out the logos after the page has scrolled down 200 pixels, you can try something like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {
        // do the swapping here
    }
});
```

As far as the "// do the swapping here" goes, if the logo image was applied as a background-image to a div (say, #logo), you could have two classes, one with the tall logo: .logo-tall, and one with the short logo: .logo-short. Then replace the "// do the swapping here" with this:

```
$("#logo").removeClass("logo-tall");
$("#logo").addClass("logo-short");
```

The relevant CSS being something like this:

```
.logo-tall {
    background: url("img/logo-tall.png") no-repeat;
}
.logo-short {
    background: url("img/logo-short.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to use HTML, you could replace "// do the swapping here" with this:

```
$('#logo img').attr("src", "img/logo-short.png");
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the // do the swapping here part?  How do I swap the image there with another?  Thanks

Comment: That's fantastic Michael. I'm not very familar with javascript so if you could please demonstrate how the logo could be swapped out via HTML (instead of swapping the class) that would be great.  Again, I appreciated all the help.